# Why is this statement not changin the array?

Tags: c++, c

```
int a[]={1,2,3,5};
    int i=1;
    a[++i]=a[i];
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[j]);
    }



output:1235;
```

why the output is `1225` and not `1335`.

I executed this program on codeblocks. In `a[++i]=a[i]`, Right to left assignment will be their,leading to `a[2]=a[1]`. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: To get 1335, you would have to change the code to well-defined C code: `++i; a[i-1]=a[i];`.

Answer (score 8):

Because `a[++i]=a[i];` is undefined behavior.

A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete. The sequence points listed in the C standard are:

> at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full
>   expression is an expression statement, or any other expression which
>   is not a subexpression within any larger expression);
>       at the ||, &&, ?:, and comma operators; and
>       at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and just before the actual call).

The standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

Comment: Also, in terms of actually implemented behaviour, the compiler is almost certainly processing the left hand side first, so effectively it is expanding it to `++i; a[i]=a[i];`

Comment: I think this might depend on compiler optimization, therefore may vary.

Comment: Yeah, it is certainly not something you can rely on; just an observation on how it is being treated here.

Answer (score 2):

```
a[++i]=a[i]; // this is undefined
```

If you only want to change single element of the array ... do it by referencing it directly:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,5};
int i=1;

a[i]++; // this will increment the ith element of the array by 1

int j;
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    printf("%d",a[j]);
}
```

**Output:**

1335

Answer (score 1):

`a[++i]=a[i];` is undefined behavior. Because according to C99 section 6.5 paragraph 2

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression.72) Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to
>   determine the value to be stored.73)

`=` is not a sequence point. Check annex C.

You are modifying the value `i` one time, but *"the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored"* is violated as you do `a[++i]`.

Check Footnote `73)` for an example of what the paragraph says.

```
73)This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
i = ++i + 1;
a[i++] = i;

while allowing
i = i + 1;
a[i] = i;
```

Therefore what the outcome will be cannot be determined. For different run and/or across different computers you can get different results. Such kind of expressions should not be used in C programming.

Comment: Though please note that footnotes in ISO standards are not normative, they are just comments about the normative text. So citing a footnote for educational purposes (as in this case) is just fine, but citing one to provide a reference or prove a point is not.

Comment: This is not to prove a point, this is to help get an idea about what the paragraph tells.

Answer (score 0):

`a[++i] = a[i]` is undefined behavior. look-up [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c).